# ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute (CreateFileGDB) ArcGIS Server 10.5

Tags: arcgis-server, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, geopackage

I am trying to convert geopackage file to geodatabase using my python script. It fails with 999999 error. This gdb is further used for the arcgis rest map service. It is only working when the service is stopped. Also, the schema lock is unchecked in the arcgis rest map directory. There is no lock on the gdb folder and no other Esri product is running on that server. I am not sure if it is related to the permissions on the server. Any suggestion is welcome.  Using Python 2.7.12 installed with ArcGIS Server 10.5

```py
import sys
import os
import arcpy
#Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\myFolder\gdb"
# To allow overwriting the outputs change the overwrite option to true.
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput  = True

gpkg_file = r"C:\myFolder\gpkg\geopk.gpkg\filename.file"
# Geodatabase Name
gdb_name = "myGdb.gdb"                                                           
out_path= r"C:\myFolder\gdb"                                           

# Process: Create File Geodatabase
    
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_path, gdb_name, out_version="CURRENT")
print("geodatabase " +gdb_name+ " is created")

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class

out_path = r"C:\myFolder\gdb\myGdb.gdb"
#geodatabase file name
gdb_file_name ="indexarea"

#arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features, out_path, out_name)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(gpkg_file, out_path, gdb_file_name)
print("***geopacakage file successfully converted into geodatabase***")
```

Comment: Try using the Copy Features tool instead of FeatureClasstoFeatureClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve that issue by changing the code
instead of using
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\myFolder\gdb"
I used
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\myFolder\gdb\myGdb.gdb"
that resolve my issue.